# Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported]

Tags: java, spring, microservices, octet-stream

I am having trouble sending parameter via swagger-ui into my spring io microservice. When I insert all parameters into swagger-ui I am getting this error: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported].

This is my controller method:

```
@Operation(summary = "Generate a pdf and sign it.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Pdf is successfully generated and signed."),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Something went wrong while generating or signing the pdf."),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "4215", description = "Something went wrong while generating or signing the pdf.")
    })
    @PostMapping(path = "/list/sequenceId/{sequenceId}",
            consumes = {MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public void generateAndSignList(@PathVariable(name = "sequenceId") Integer sequenceId,
                                    @RequestPart(value="sign", required = false)
                                    boolean sign,
                                    @RequestPart String pathToTemplate,
                                    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
                                            content = @Content(mediaType = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
                                                    schema = @Schema(name = "itemWrapper",
                                                            ref = "#/components/schemas/Map")))
                                    @RequestPart ItemWrapper itemWrapper)
            throws SftpException {

        List<Item> list = itemWrapper.getList();
        double totalSum = itemWrapper.getTotalSum();

        Session session =  this.sftpUpload.getSession();
        ChannelSftp channel = this.sftpUpload.getChannel(session);

        Integer number = this.sftpUpload.numberOfPdfs(channel, sequenceId, ".pdf") + 1;

        Generated generatedPdf = pdfGenerator.generateListFromHtml(pathToTemplate, list, totalSum,
                number.toString());

        if(sign) {
            byte[] signedPdf = this.signingService.signPdf(generatedPdf.getPdfContent());
            generatedPdf.setPdfContent(signedPdf);
        }

        //this.sftpUpload.uploadPdf(channel, generatedPdf.getPdfContent(), sequenceId, generatedPdf.getFileName());
        //this.sftpUpload.disconnectChannelAndSession(channel, session);
    }
```

These are my dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-parser-v3</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>9.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.64</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.64</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!--SWAGGER-UI-->
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0-M1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- SFTP -->
            <groupId>com.github.mwiede</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is my OpenApi @Bean:

```
@Bean
    public OpenAPI api() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSchemas("Map", new Schema<Map<String, Object>>()
                                .addProperties("< * >", new ObjectSchema())
                        ))
                .info(apiInfo());
    }

    private io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info apiInfo() {
        return new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info()
                .title("Pdf generator, signer and uploader API")
                .description("Micro-service generates, signs and uploads pdfs to sftp.")
                .version("1.0")
                .contact(new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Contact()
                        .email("mail@mail.com")
                        .name("name")
                        .url("https://www.url.com"));
    }
```

and I am adding a print-screen from my swagger-ui:
[print-screen from my swagger-ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSdmx.jpg)

I tried using various @Schema and @Component annotations. I would like my code to work.